# Stuck in infinite loop when attempting to receive user choice from modal and pass to CanDeactivate

Tags: angular

I have a settings page in my app that I want to guard so that the user cannot navigate away from the page while they have unsaved settings. Instead I want to give them the choice to navigate and lose their settings or to stay on the page.

To do this I have a CanDeactivate guard set up and a modal that uses an EventEmitter to emit a `true` if the user chooses to navigate away from the page. I have subscribed to the EventEmitter's observable within my CanDeactivate method assuming that when the `true` value is emitted the subscription will pick it up, then I can return true from the method and the route will deactivate.

However this isn't what's occuring. What's actually happening is when I click on the Continue button on my modal the modal keeps reappearing. I know this is happening due to the CanDeactivate guard still being active and therefore tries to prevent the user from deactivating the route by opening another modal.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to subscribe to the EventEmitter output so that I can navigate away from the page if the user chooses to.

CanDeactivateGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate {
  component: Object;
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

  constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog, private router: Router){

  }

  canDeactivate(component: SettingsComponent,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log("canDeactivate activated");

    console.log(route);
    console.log(state);

    if(component.unsavedSettingsExist()) {
      const modalRef = this._dialog.open(UnsavedSettingsModalComponent, {
        data: {}
      });
      console.log(modalRef);
      modalRef.componentInstance.continueEmitter.subscribe(res => {
        {
            console.log("res ", res);
            this.router.navigate(["/"])
            return true;
        }
      });
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

UnsavedSettingsModal

```
export class UnsavedSettingsModalComponent extends AbstractBaseComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() continueEmitter: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(baseService: BaseService,
              private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UnsavedSettingsModalComponent>,

              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {}) {
    super(baseService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  continue(){
    console.log("emitted");
    this.continueEmitter.emit(true);
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is happening because of the `this.router.navigate(["/"])` line. When you click to continue, your subscribe tries to navigate the app to '/' route which triggers `canDeactivate` again. Why are you rerouting to `/` route? Let the app navigate to the route which causes `canDeactivate`. If you remove `this.router.navigate(["/"])` line, it should works.

Comment: @user2216584 I know it's being caused by the call to `router.navigate`, the problem is that if I don't include that line the app doesn't navigate to anywhere despite returning true. The value is emitted and picked up by the subscription so `console.log("res", res)` triggers but nothing after that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is fixed like this, in guard:

```
  return modalRef.componentInstance.continueEmitter.pipe(first());
```

return the observable and complete after one emission. the guard will subscribe to it.  the value returned will handle the navigation, false blocks, true allows. also update the return type of the guard to `Observable<boolean> | boolean`. Your current set up won't work because the return statement inside your async subscribe never reaches the guard due to the nature of async operations.

then in modal:

```
close() {
  this.continueEmitter.emit(false);
  this.dialogRef.close();
}
```

it always has to emit something for the guard to work